# HTML pixel positioning and bootstrap confusing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, pixel

I will admit that this question is not phrased well, mostly because I don't know how to phrase it well. The thing is, I have been rather confused on how to position elements in my page, while using Bootstrap to keep the website responsive.

As in, I find it difficult to use pixels because for some reason, I have this idea in my head that pixels are used with non-responsive websites. So whenever I want to make something bigger, I am quite unsure how to do that, to not conflict with bootstrap.

Should I go deeper in Bootstrap or HTML/CSS to get over this thought problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create responsive websites try to use media queries. 
example

```
@media ( max-width:767px){
             p{
                  font-size:16px;
              }
         }
         @media ( max-width:480px){
             p{
                  font-size:14px;
              }
         }
         @media ( max-width:320px){
             p{
                  font-size:12px;
              }
         }
```

in this case font-size will change as per the size of the device. you can use pixel but side by side you have to manage media queries for responsive design.

***Hope this will give some rough idea.***

Comment: Would you say to not use Bootstrap then?

Comment: Bootstrap is the best framework for responsive design. but for few things you have to write media query.

Comment: I do understand that, but I would rather want to learn for now how to learn to work effectively within bootstrap, and what I can and cannot do within its limits. The problem is that when I want to use pixels for example, I don't know whether it will mess up the grids.